# JSON Display of a particular answer

Tags: jquery, json

I would like to alert() different answers in JSON from a survey . I can display all the content but I have some difficulties to display only selected  answers. As it is a survey the answers changes every time. Here is my code:

```
var resultAsString = JSON.stringify(survey.data);
  alert(resultAsString)
```

And here is what I obtain in the alert

```
  {"question1":"item4","question2":["faire","lion","elephant "],"question3":{"Row 1":"Column 2"}}
```

I would like to alert() only the answers seperately (i.e item4; ["faire","lion","elephant "];{"Row 1":"Column 2"}) I have tried the code below but nothing is displayed. Could you please help me.

```
   alert(resultAsString.question1)
   alert(resultAsString.question2)
   alert(resultAsString.question3)
```

Comment: Do not use the `resultAsString` but the `survey.data`. Liike this `alert(survey.data.question1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are stringifying the JSON and then accessing it like an object with key/value pair. Please do it like this

```
var result = survey.data;

alert(result.question1);
alert(result.question2);
alert(result.question3);
```

Obviously you are going to have more question answers in this array with time so accessing each question separately cannot be a good solution.

Try this.

```
var result = survey.data;
var resultKeys = Object.keys(result);

for( var i = 0; i < resultKeys.length; i++ ) {
 if(typeof result[resultKeys[i]] === 'object')
   alert(JSON.stringify(result[resultKeys[i]]));
 else
   alert(result[resultKeys[i]]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Yes it is a better way to do it. But it does work for question3 "question3":{"Row 1":"Column 2"}}. It displays [object][object]. Maybe do you know the reason and how to fix it? thanks again

Comment: Yes it should. Could you explain me how to accept your answer ? Where should I click? (I am new here...) Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var resultAsString1 = JSON.stringify(survey.data.question1);
alert(resultAsString1);
```